# Databases for Enthalpy of Solution and Ionic Radii for Ionic Salts

Tags: enthalpy, ionic-compounds, databases

I am looking to investigate the relation between experimental enthalpies of solution and theoretical enthalpies of solution calculated using theoretical equations for the lattice enthalpy and hydration enthalpy for ionic salts. I read that because of the covalent nature of ionic salts with a lower difference in electronegativity, the experimental lattice enthalpy of these salts is actually greater than would be expected theoretically. Would this be worth investigating?

To investigate this, I am looking for public databases with data for the solution enthalpy and ionic radii of ionic salts however I cannot find any other than the CRC handbook for physics and chemistry (and only the 85th version; would it be better to get a more recent version or should these data be the same in more recent versions?). I would like to use more than one database so could someone please let me know of any other public databases with these data?

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to the [NIST Chemistry WebBook](https://webbook.nist.gov/chemistry/) for thermodynamic data by species or reactions. I also found a database for lattice enthalpy [here](https://calculla.com/lattice_energy_table). For ionic radii, you can refer to [this database](http://abulafia.mt.ic.ac.uk/shannon/).

Comment: I am trying to find data for the enthalpy of solution specifically but I can't find it anywhere other than the CRC handbook. The NIST chemistry webbook does not seem to include it either. Do you know where I could find data for the enthalpy of solution?

Comment: I made a brief search and found similar results...Maybe you should look for research papers on specific compounds instead.